# Brightway2: SyntaxError: at expr='ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off' when bw.write_database()

Tags: brightway

I'm using an LCI dataset from an Excel file.
I used it several times to conduct LCA with Brightway2.
I created a new product in that same Excle file and the first steps of importation went right, I mean these ones:

```
imp = bw.ExcelImporter(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "LCI_CW.xlsx"))
imp.apply_strategies()
imp.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
imp.match_database("ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off",
                   fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
imp.statistics()
```

When checking with `imp.write_excel()` the activities match,etc.

BUT

When using `imp.write_database()`

I come with this error:

```
SyntaxError: at expr='ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off'
```

Any idea where this mistake could be hidden? I checked my use of `expr='ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off'`, etc.

More details below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\...\asteval\asteval.py", line 254, in parse
    out = ast.parse(text)

  File "C:\...\lib\ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\...\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "C:\...\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14440/3637353444.py", line 1, in <module>
    imp.write_database()

  File "C:\...\bw2io\importers\excel.py", line 277, in write_database
    super(ExcelImporter, self).write_database(**kwargs)

  File "C:\...\bw2io\importers\base_lci.py", line 266, in write_database
    self.write_database_parameters(activate_parameters, delete_existing)

  File "C:\...\bw2io\importers\excel.py", line 270, in write_database_parameters
    super(ExcelImporter, self).write_database_parameters(

  File "C:\...\bw2io\importers\base_lci.py", line 118, in write_database_parameters
    parameters.new_database_parameters(

  File "C:\...\bw2data\parameters.py", line 1319, in new_database_parameters
    DatabaseParameter.recalculate(database)

  File "C:\...\bw2data\parameters.py", line 348, in recalculate
    new_symbols = get_new_symbols(data.values(), set(data))

  File "C:\...\bw2data\parameters.py", line 1526, in get_new_symbols
    nf.generic_visit(interpreter.parse(formula))

  File "C:\...\asteval\asteval.py", line 256, in parse
    self.raise_exception(None, msg='Syntax Error', expr=text)

  File "C:\...\asteval\asteval.py", line 244, in raise_exception
    raise exc(self.error_msg)

  File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: at expr='ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off'
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off' is showing up in a definition of a database parameter, which isn't a valid Python expression, i.e. it is the same as typing in a Python prompt:

```
In [1]: ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off
  File "<ipython-input-1-db6705818daf>", line 1
    ecoinvent 3.7 cut-off
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

We could help debug the Excel file if you are comfortable sharing it. Otherwise I don't see a way to help understand the specific formatting error.

Comment: Again, thank you for your reply Chris.
I have changed the names of my parameters and it works. Could one of the following names be the cause of the SyntaxError?

natural_gas / 
elec_use / 
lifespan / 
shdg_device / 
thermal_curtain / 
sg / 
sg_coated / 
dg / 
dg_coated / 
dg_coated_krypton / 
dg_2coatings / 
tg_coated / 
tg_2coatings / 
tg_2coatings_krypton / 
g_2coatings_xenon / 
ccf / 
dg_vacuum / 
dg_smart / 
dsf / 

I added "param_" before each of them and it works.